# Removing data from an entity type

Tags: commerce, 9, payment-gateways

I am trying to remove a problematic payment gateway module and getting the following message when trying to uninstall it:

> There is data for the bundle Authorize.net (Accept.js) on the entity type Payment. Please remove all content before uninstalling the module.

How do I clear data for the entity type? Do I need to edit the database directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Authorize.Net module defines a `PaymentType` plugin that serves as the bundle for `Payment` entities created by the Accept.js payment gateway. I don't recall *why* we decided to use a custom payment type there, but so long as payment entities exist in your database of that bundle, you will not be able to uninstall the Authorize.Net module.

If you're able to do so without harming your store, you would need to delete all of those payments. I wouldn't recommend deleting them directly from the database, as it's not a simply search and delete operation for entities. In the past we've solved tasks like this by writing a simple drush command or other server-side script to load and batch delete entities.

The alternative would be to attempt to convert them to the default payment type. I don't know if that will break anything off the top of my head, but you can give it a shot or see if anyone in the Drupal Commerce Slack knows what side effects that might generate.